# Wordpress query string rewrite .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the minute my .htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I want to be able to turn this page:

```
/car-details/?make=Ford&model=Focus
```

in to:

```
/car-details/car-info/Ford/Focus
```

including the extra "/car-info/".

I've tried quite a few combinations but I'm getting nowhere... any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Is `/car-details/?make=Ford&model=Focus` being served by WP?

Comment: Nope, I'm doing it myself from a custom template

Comment: True but that is still being served by WP right?

Comment: It is being served by WP, yes

Comment: That's the reason rewriting to pretty URL won't work since WP expected original `/car-details/?make=Ford&model=Focus` as REQUEST_URI

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as `/car-details/car-info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)` should work wonders:

```
RewriteRule /car-details/car-info/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /car-details/?make=$1&model=$2
```

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it and also had been trying RewriteRule ^car-details/car-info/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /car-details/?make=$1&model=$2 (with caret) but no go... maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place?